# ng-template inside ng-for creates only 1 time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using dynamic form loader angular 6 inside `ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let field of item.fields" >
   <ng-template pf-host ></ng-template>
</div>
```

And the problem is ng-template creates only in first time. There are 4 fields and ng-template only inside the first one.

**loadComponents()** also have a loop such as my HTML markup. And creates 4 times.

```
loadComponent() {
    this.item.fields.forEach(item => {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        const viewContainerRef = this.pfHost.viewContainerRef;
        const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
         });
}
```

How can I make it correctly? In the first item first component, in second item second component etc?
Now there are for components in the first item. Other items are empty.

*EDIT:  ANSWER*

Solved this by using @ViewChildren

```
@ViewChildren(ProductFormDirective) pfHost: QueryList<ProductFormDirective>;
```

And then in loadComponents() iterate by index.

```
        for (let i = 0; i < this.item.fields.length; i++) {
            const item = this.item.fields[i];
            const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
            const pfHostToArray = this.pfHost.toArray();
            const viewContainerRef = pfHostToArray[i].viewContainerRef;
            const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
            console.log('component created');
            const inst = <ProductFormInnerComponent>componentRef.instance;
            (<ProductFormInnerComponent>componentRef.instance).metadata = item;
            item.componentRef = componentRef;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a nagging feeling you are not really using the right approach for your use case here... What are you trying to achieve, and why? Functionally I mean.

Anyhow, your for loop in your component will only find the first view-child matching the pf-host selector, so it will create components inside the first one only.

Comment: Please use comments for suggestion

Comment: I want to create a table. This div with ngFor creates row of this table. LoadComponent create input components base on its type. It calls 4 times, such as ngFor in div. I want that first component from loadComponent will be in first div, second in second and etc.